# jQuery misbehaving in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm having a problem where certain bit of code is working perfectly across all browsers until I come to Safari where it's giving me issues.  I inherited this code, and I'm not a jQuery expert so needless to say I'm a bit baffled:

```
var xt_begin=$('#begin')[0];            
xt_begin.currentTime = 0; 
xt_begin.play();
```

"#begin" is an audio element that was set in the HTML that's using this code and the .play() function is in a jQuery plugin that's being used ([Link to plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/)).

In all browsers except for Safari, play is being defined as if xt_begin were an object of that timer class.  In safari, however, it remains undefined and the code stops working.  I have no idea how this happens or how to fix it.  I can post more code if need be, any help would be appreciated.

**Update

Upon further investigation it turns out it is a DOM element, and I'm a bit thick.  However, Safari seems to have a problem recognizing audio elements for some reason.  It's identifying it as an "object HTMLelement" whereas Firefox shows it as "object HTMLAudioElement".  I'm still stumped on this one.

**SOLVED

Apparently Safari needs quicktime installed on your desktop for it to use audio elements.  That's gonna make this app I'm fixing completely useless, but at least I know now.  Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: What is `$('#begin').length`? Does jQ really finds the element in Safari? Or maybe you want to use `$(...).eq(0)` instead of `$(...)[0]`.

Comment: Unlikely that the play() and currentTime have anything to do with your timer plug in. An HTML audio element has those methods already, and they are used for setting the play position and beginning play of the audio.

Comment: This is what console is exactly for - **debugging!** Just output each property / method using calls like `console.log('xt_begin:', xt_begin, 'type:', typeof xt_begin)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Really just a comment. The statement:

```
var xt_begin = $('#begin')[0];
```

is effectively the same as:

```
var xt_begin = document.getElementById('begin');
```

so `xt_begin` is either a DOM element or `undefined` (jQuery) or `null` (plain JS). Which is it?

In any case, you should probably follow with:

```
if (xt_begin) {
  /* do stuff with xt_begin */
}
```

to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var xt_begin = document.getElementById('begin');
```

Instead of the jQuery line. That works across all browsers and will at least tell you if you have a jQuery problem or a Safari/web page problem.

Comment: Doesn't really help when they need to call `.play` on it which is a jQuery plugin method, requiring a jQuery object, which would be `$("#begin")`

Comment: The question indicated it was an audio element, which has both a currentTime and play() method that have nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Yes that's nice, but if you read the question, it specifically says "and the .play() function is in a jQuery plugin that's being used (Link to plugin)", so I would think that requires a jQuery object...

Comment: So although I agree with you because those are true about an `audio` element, I'm not sure it matters because of the plugin information provided

Comment: And the questioner also states that they aren't familiar with jQuery. What this is is an audio element that is trying to play with the currentTime set to the start of the audio element. This is a technique that forces the audio element to revert to the start if it was or has been played.